# Hosting widgets inside fragments

Tags: android

Is it possible? supported?
I want to make an app that hosts widgets in fragments, I know how to do it on activity but don't know if it works with fragments.

Comment: When you say "widgets", do you really mean "widgets" (e.g., `Button`), or do you mean "app widgets" (i.e., interactive elements that can be added to a home screen)?

Comment: "Interactive widgets" was not one of your available choices. When you say "widgets", do you really mean "widgets" (i.e., subclasses of `View`) or do you really mean "app widgets" (as described on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)?

Comment: App widgets.. the one you put on desktop

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you mean AppWidgets, so take a look at this
https://github.com/DagW/FragmentHomescreen

It contains a complete example project for adding widgets to fragments in a viewpager.

It also contains code for adding appwidgets programatically.